# Why a copy of my.ini of other MySQL installation not working on my PC

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have two MySQL installations on two different PCs not connected to each other. I made some changes in the **my.ini** file of PC 1 and tried using this file on PC 2, but MySQL service fails to start. Why the copied My.INI not working on my PC when both installations were configured same and the instance names also similar?

Comment: does it give any error messages in the error log?

Comment: No it doesn't give error. It just displays: "Could not start NySQL service".

Comment: Three(3) Questions : 1) What is the version of MySQL on each machine ? 2) Was MySQL installed the exact same way on each machine ? Is the default path of MySQL C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Version 5.x\ ???

Comment: @Rolando: YES to all your questions. Version is 5.5.

Comment: Are the two PCs running the exact same version of Windows ? Do you use 'net start mysql' to start mysql ? is mysql installed properly as a service on both PCs ?

Comment: What version of Windows are the two machines running ???

Comment: Are your users that are starting the service the same on both machines? (admittedly a bit of a leap bt just throwing it out there).

Comment: Both are using Windows 7. MySQL service start automatically on both.

Comment: Have you checked that the my.ini config'ed paths for basedir/datadir actually exist on the non-working machine? And that the [mysqld] port= config is not already in use by another application on that machine (netstat -a from a windows command prompt will list the ports in use)? You can also put the two .ini files on the same PC and do a "windiff file1.ini file2.ini" to make sure the only differences are exactly what you think they should be. Try reducing the differences as much as possible and retrying startup to see if one of them is causing the fault.

Comment: As you provide details about your setup, be sure to edit your question to include those details so others can see them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make sure MySQL evens runs properly apart from the service.

Open a DOS Window Session and run these commands

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5\bin"
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5\bin> start mysqld
```

When you launch mysqld like this, **mysqld expects my.ini to be in the parent directory**, which is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5. Using start in DOS will open another DOS Window as a background task. If any error messages appear in that window and that forked DOS Session quickly disappears from the screen, check the Task Manager to see if mysqld is running. If it is, you should be able to log into mysql. If mysqld is not in the Task Manager, launch it as a foreground task like this:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5\bin> mysqld
```

If the DOS prompt appears after some error messages, then mysqld failed. If error messages come up and the DOS prompt does not appear, mysqld is up.

If the settings you configured in my.ini on PC 2 is not in `SHOW VARIABLES;` then **mysqld cannot see the my.ini**. To reiterate, **mysqld expects my.ini to be in the parent directory**.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your my.ini files side-by-side, there must be some setting that makes it impossible to start your server, maybe some InnoDB setting. Check your system's [event log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-Event-Viewer) under Windows System Logs > System (wording may be a bit different, I don't have English windows). There you will have a more detailed information on service fail reason.